# Facebook Share with custom values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-sharer

I try to develop a custom facebook share button where when you click on it a post

from my website with custom values will be shared by facebook users wall and an

email will be saved on my `MySql`database. Especially I have an `HTML` document

where I have the code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javas.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a href="http://www.example.com" data-image="article-1.jpg" data-title="Article Title" data-desc="Some description for this article" class="btnShare">Share</a>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </body> 
</html>
```

And the Javascript code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


$('.btnShare').click(function(){
    elem = $(this);
    postToFeed(elem.data('title'), elem.data('desc'), elem.prop('href'), elem.data('image'));

    return false;
});


});


window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
FB.init({
    appId: '4534535353654645', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true }); 
};
(function(d, debug){var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if(d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; 
    js.async = true;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);}(document, /*debug*/ false));
function postToFeed(title, desc, url, image){
var obj = {method: 'feed',link: url, picture: 'http://www.url.com/images/'+image,name: title,description: desc};
function callback(response){}
FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

The result is that It does not work the share and it shows [image]

I am not sure if my website should support `https`

How can I fix this to show the share button ?
There is any way to handle share button click so when it is clicked to save the email ?

Comment: You can't post custom values in someone's wall so easily. Does your FB App have the required permissions?

Comment: I want to add my title, picture description and so on. I think this can happen but my code does not work correctly.

Comment: Can you paste the full url of the popup dialog here? Please ensure that the value for the redirect_uri matches with the "App Domains" field in your App Dashboard --> Settings tab.